# Running server from inside Chroot in ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, ubuntu, chroot

Due to the peculiar  nature of the application, I'm thinking of running servers such as Apache, Tomcat from within a chroot environment.
Using schroot and debootstrap, I'm able to create a clone of my 10.04 ubuntu(minimal ubuntu) inside chroot directory. I've install tomcat and apache inside chroot . But how do I access these two servers?

1. Can I access them like a normal apache/tomcat installed on parent server?
2. Can the parent OS access the apache/tomcat of chroot os?

First, which of these options is possible. Second, any caveats that I should handle with each of these options.

I want something like

```
 Internet ---> [Main host Ubuntu 10.04 Apache ----> (chroot ubuntu Tomcat)  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chroot`ing is one of the simplest forms of virtual machines. If your application is security-sensitive, you might consider running a more full-featured solution, such as [OpenVZ](http://wiki.openvz.org/Main_Page), [Xen](http://www.xen.org/), [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page), [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or commercial solutions, such as [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) and a few others.

That being said, you should really consider to view your chrooted OS as just another host in your network. When you'll be using just `chroot`, you can access it as `localhost` (127.0.0.1) with some port number you'll assign to it (chrooted system will effectively share port assignations with parent system), while using other virtualization solutions allows you to assign a normal separate IP to each virtual machine and run it much as you would run a separate physical box.

chrooting is fairly "weak" security solution, is parent and child share a lot of resources almost without limitations (i.e. memory, CPU, process pool, disc space, privileges, sockets, etc). They only limitation in fact is limited filesystem access (i.e. chrooted applications can access only a portion of whole file system), although it provides some degree of isolation.

Comment: Virtualization would probably be an overkill for me. Which one of OpenVZ etc is a really lightweight application?

Comment: OpenVZ is a very lightweight solution: it's basically chroot with added separation of network stack, resource limiting, disc quotas, etc, etc. Can you explain in more detail, how exactly security-sensitive your application is? I.e. what are you trying to protect using chroot?

Comment: Well, we will utilize lots of third party libraries, jars in tomcat which may be of poor quality and even downright malicious. So it becomes necessary that tomcat runs inside chroot sort of environment. I just want that access to system's real files/data should be limited.